# Transfer of baggage Turkish airlines to Oman Air - LGW to HYD

Tags: transit, luggage

Our family (2 adults and 3 children) are travelling from London Gatwick via Turkish Airlines, we transit at Istanbul and take a connecting flight to Muscat. Our stay at Muscat is only 2 hours and 10 mins

From Muscat we have our final flight going to Hyderabad, India.
All of itinerary was booked via lastminute.com and all flights are in one ticket (single e-ticket number and 2 PNR's)

My questions are

1. Will I need to collect my baggage from Muscat International, go through immigration, collect baggage and then re-checkin with Oman Air?
2. Will 2 hours be enough to complete this given we'll have at least 4 bags?

---

Thanks for your reply

1. yes my eticket numbers indeed start with 235
2. I put my PNR on turkish airlines website and can see the full journey through to my final destination. So yes looks like a single booking
   3.I did call the airlines - they suggest to check with the agent while checking in on the day. Lastminute say speak to airline.

I just hope based on the agreement's between airlines they will transfer my baggage as Turkish airlines can clearly see I just have a 2 hour wait which is not enough to clear immigration, covid rules and collect baggage for re-checkin.
Also based on https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/any-questions/transfer-transit-passengers/index.html it looks like turkish do take responsibility to transfer luggage even if its not their airline.

Answer (score 2):

Oman Air has an interlining agreement with Turkish Air, so they CAN transfer your baggage. https://www.omanair.com/gbl/en/alliances-and-partners

Whether they will, depends on how exactly your ticket was booked. Unfortunately if you book through a third party, that's always tricky.

1. Check the first three digits of your e-ticket number and look up the airline code here http://www.kovrik.com/sib/travel/airline-codes.txt. That should either be 910 for Oman Air or 235 for Turkish. That would be your marketing carrier and the airline that's "responsible". If the code doesn't exist or is a completely unrelated airline, your number is probably not an e-ticket number.
2. Go to both airline's website and put in your PNRs. See if they show up there. If your entire trips is visible, than it's a single booking and chances are good that your bags are checked through
3. Call the airlines and/or lastminute and ask

Keep in mind that if your bags are NOT checked through, you may have to leave the transit area and you may have to meet all Visa and Covid requirements for entry into Oman.

Comment: Technically there are two types of "Interline" agreements - ticket and baggage.  The referenced URL appears to confirm Oman has a ticketing interline agreement (which means one airline can be issue tickets with flights on the other airline), but doesn't explicitly state they have a baggage interline agreement which is what's required for checking-through baggage. Given TK and WY (Oman Air) have codeshare flights I'd be fairly sure they do have a baggage interline agreement - I'm just pointing out that the link above doesn't actually confirm that as implied.